# Groovy. How can I get json elements in array

Tags: json, groovy, get, httpbuilder

there is such a JSON: https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all
I just want to have a choice "translations" -> "ita" -> "common"

```
HTTPBuilder getHttpBuilder() {
    new HTTPBuilder('https://restcountries.com/')
}

def http = httpBuilder.request(Method.GET, ContentType.JSON){
    uri.path = 'v3.1/all'
    uri.query = [fields: 'translations,ita,common']
    response.success = { resp, json ->
        log.error(json.toString()) //string
        log.error(JsonOutput.toJson(json).br) //json
        log.error(JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(json))) //formated json
    }
}
```

but I always get either a general view or nothing of what is needed
Help me to understand! Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide example of expected result.

Comment: @daggett Hello! Thanks for answering. What does your comment imply? How exactly should I edit the question so that it meets the requirements?

I wrote that I need to get a common from an available API

What else should I write??

Comment: how expected result of your code should look like? because i can't understand what you want to do. there is no such fields: `ita,common` in response

Comment: @daggett 
The code given in the example doesn't really reflect what could lead to the result :)
If you go to: https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all
you can see these fields: "common": "Mauritania"
for example: 
"ita": {
        "official": "Repubblica islamica di Mauritania",
        "common": "Mauritania"

Comment: As I can see by documentation of this API you can filter only top-level fields. Any sublevel field access you should do in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution for me. Maybe someone else will stumble upon it too.

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.Method
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

HTTPBuilder getHttpBuilder() {
    new HTTPBuilder('https://restcountries.com/')
}

def http = httpBuilder.request(Method.GET, ContentType.JSON){
    uri.path = 'v3.1/all'    
}

def tempJson = JsonOutput.toJson(http)
def resultParseJson = parseJsonText(tempJson)
def needResult = resultParseJson.translations.ita.common

def parseJsonText(String textJson){
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    return jsonSlurper.parseText(textJson)
}
```

needResult - what I need.
Perhaps someone will have a more beautiful or correct solution - I will be grateful. But so far this result is satisfactory.